# Best way to serialize obtained folders and files in XML using c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have been working on obtaining files and folders using c#:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path)
        {
            Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
            queue.Enqueue(path);
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                path = queue.Dequeue();
                try
                {
                    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                    {
                        queue.Enqueue(subDir);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                string[] files = null;
                try
                {
                    files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                if (files != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                    {
                        yield return files[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And then I got output in console, everything respectively like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                     foreach (string file in GetFiles("C:\\"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

So... I need to serialize this into a XML file with the condition(folders and files with length smaller than 8, extension takes 3 characters). Condition is not important at the moment. After reading a lot of useful stuff, I could not find an appropriate solution. Regards.

Comment: (1) Store them in some data structure, (2) serialize using `XmlSerializer` or `XDocument` and (3) come back with a specific problem related to it :)

Comment: @OndrejTucny OK, someone thinks my code is good. What is the best structure to fill? About XmlSerializer, yes, that is obvious, but I needed to know if my code is good and to get hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote code back in January.  See if this helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WriteFileNamesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```